# Set attribute on slice of a series

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched pretty thoroughly for an answer to this on this site, and haven't been able to find anything. Is there a way to set an attribute on a slice of a series? Something like this throws an error--

```
mySeries = pd.Series([1,2,3])
setattr(mySeries.iloc[:2], 'myMean', 1.5)
getattr(mySeries.iloc[:2], 'myMean')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its a good idea to include said error in your post.

Comment: series are `One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html Not quite sure what you are trying to do with series.

Comment: Why not just `myMean = np.mean(mySeries.iloc[:2])`? Why hard-code the mean value when you can just have it calculated in your script?

Answer (score 1):

well you can do it, but this is a dirty hack and it's not useful at all:

```
In [318]: mySeries.myMean = mySeries.mean()

In [319]: mySeries
Out[319]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [320]: mySeries.myMean
Out[320]: 2.0
```

**NOTE:** as @jpp has mentioned in comments it might be also very dangerous if you will overwrite one of the existing attributes.

imagine that this series has been changed:

```
In [321]: mySeries *= 10

In [322]: mySeries
Out[322]:
0    10
1    20
2    30
dtype: int64
```

your attribute now shows an incorrect (old) value:

```
In [323]: mySeries.myMean
Out[323]: 2.0
```

PS i don't think we can have an independent attribute for a *slice*